# Incorrect Wi-Fi password message

Tags: iphone, ios

I am on iphone 6+ and ios 8.1.2.I keep getting the following error

Incorrect Wi-FI password message for Wi-Fi networks that do not exist . I am not sure why is my phone trying to access these networks if they do not exist of the wifi list and why am I getting this error.

PS: I can connect to the all wi-fi netwoks i want to . It is just these random error messages popping up on my mobile suggesting password is not correct for some "AndroidAP" wifi network that is confusing me.

Comment: it will not try to connect to unknown wifi, it will show them but not connect without your permission, remove those from your profile if you have them saved

Comment: I have not saved any of them . Which is the reason I am surprised that I am getting these prompts

Comment: now that is surprising, something you have is trying to force you to use wifi you have not used before?